# Rails 3.2.6 + rake aborted! Application has been already initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on a rails 3.2.6 application (upgraded from 3.0 to 3.1 and then to 3.2) and I have to following problem: I cannot run rake tasks anymore.

The command **bundle exec rake db:migrate** returns

**rake aborted!
Application has been already initialized.**

I'm using rake 0.9.2.2 and I already tried downgrading to version 0.9.2 without chance.

Many thanks in advance.

Mauro

UPDATE:

I get the same problem if I try to run thinking sphinx tasks...

**SOLVED:
the guy who worked on the app before added APPNAME::Application.initialize! in a library file, but the initialization is already triggered in config/environment.rb.**

Comment: are you deploy it on heroku or local?

Comment: I think the problem isn't rake I have rails 3.2.6 and rake 0.9.2.2, it works fine

Comment: what vs of ruby are you using ?

Comment: I have other apps running rails 3.2.6 and rake 0.9.2.2 without any problem. I'm using rvm, and I installed ruby-1.9.2-p320

Answer (score 0):

Check by following commands:
`rake db:create`After installing bundle with `bundle install` command.

Comment: Db already exist. I get the same error if I run **bundle exec rake db:reset**

Comment: then only run: rake db:migrate

Comment: Same problem ... I also tried to delete all tables from DB, but I got the same error.